# How to remove content within the &lt and &gt javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a content that contains a string of elements along with images. ex:

```
var str= <p>&lt;img src=\"v\"&gt;fwefwefw&lt;/img&gt;</p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

the text that is within the `&lt` and `&gt` is a dirty tag and I would like to remove it along with the content that is within it. the tag is generated dynamically and hence could be any tag i.e `<div>, <a>, <h1> etc...`.

the expected output : `<p></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>`

however with this code, im only able to remove the tags and not the content inside it.

```
str.replaceAll(/&lt;.*?&gt;/g, "");
```

it renders like this which is not what im looking for:

```
<p>fwefwefw</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

how can I possibly remove the `&` tags along with the content so that I get rid of dirty tags and text inside it?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rozjn8m/

thanks

Comment: You have a malformed HTML string there IMG does not have a closing </img> tag nor a stream of human readable content. Your escaped html string looks like this :: `<p><img src="v">fwefwefw</img></p>`
Do you think this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the question mark.

```
var str= "<p>&lt;img src=\"v\"&gt;fwefwefw&lt;/img&gt;</p><p><br></p><p><br></p>";
console.log(str.replaceAll(/&lt;.*&gt;/g, ""));
```

Comment: That will fail if there is another (real) tag with such content.

Answer (score 2):

A safe way is to use a DOM parser, visiting each text node, where then each text can be cleaned separately. This way you are certain the DOM structure is not altered; only the texts:

```js
let str= "<p>&lt;img src=\"v\"&gt;fwefwefw&lt;/img&gt;</p><p><br></p><p><br></p>";

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
let walk = doc.createTreeWalker(doc.body, 4, null, false);
let node = walk.nextNode();
while (node) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/<.*>/gs, "");
    node = walk.nextNode();
}
let clean = doc.body.innerHTML;

console.log(clean);
```

This will also work when you have more than one `<p>` element that has such content.